# calling Web Method inside codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I need to call a Web method inside my code behind file using `jquery ajax` and also using vanilla `javascript`

I can do this with asp.net `PageMethods` and also can do with asp.net MVC(calling controller method).

With `Page Methods` it's like this

```
 PageMethods.MethodName(...);
```

And I know how to call methods in `WCF service` or `WebService` But I need to call Method inside aspx.cs file from `javascript` or `Jquery`

How can I do this?

I have tried `[WebMethod]` on `Web Method` which is static but it's not working. I need both `Get` and `Post` solution

Comment: Why do you want to use Jquery to call a Web Method on the server side?

Comment: "But I need to call Method inside aspx.cs file from javascript or Jquery"  You can't JavaScript runs in the browser not on the server, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BenRobinson I meant through ajax

Comment: ajax is a browser technology, it doesn't make sense to want to use it in the code behind. Are you saying you want to make an http request from your code behind? You certainly can do that but that has nothing to do with ajax, jquery or javascript.

Comment: @BenRobinson I want to call webmethod with ajax call. what so complicated about that?

Comment: There is nothing complicated about calling a webmethod with ajax, using javascript in the browser, you just can't do it in the code behind which is what you said you want to do.

Comment: So are you saying I can not call webmethod inside codebehind but can call webmethod inside webservice?

Comment: You can call a web method from code behind, its just a static method server side, but ajax is not involved, there is no get there is no post you are just calling a static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, you do need static methods decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute.  It's been a while, but here is an example of some code I'm using on an older project:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AjaxBridge.aspx/GetPatientInfo",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{'personID':'" + personID + "'}",
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

We have a specialized page called AjaxBridge.aspx that does nothing but handle ajax calls like this (I don't like the design of this personally).  You can embed them directly into your current page or UserControl, too.  Just be sure to reference the correct path to that either relative to the current page or an absolute path.

The actual service code that gets called looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static PersonItem GetPatientInfo(int personID)
{
    ...
}
```

In order to support HTTP GET you may need to add the following attribute to your service method:

```
[ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet = true)]
```

And of course, change the ajax jquery method type to GET

Comment: Yes, it works for me just fine.  Try it and let me know if you have success

Comment: I will try later but bc ur confident I am accepting it. What technology u currently work on, MVC?

Comment: This is for straight ASP.NET WebForms.  If you are using MVC, you can use this in a similar fashion (in jQuery), but the code-behind likely needs to be handled as an action in your controller

Comment: ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods do NOT support GET, but rather only POST requests. This is a security feature.